# How to Indicate Information cannot be Viewed?

Tags: gui-design, data

I have a system where we show customer name in a list, but for certain items, the customer name needs to be confidential. Right now our system displays *name hidden*. We are thinking of doing something that is more visually appealing and just as understandable. One option is to have a generic name that is blurred out. Or maybe make it look like redacted document? I am posting this to find out if I am missing some standard way of doing this or maybe someone will have a better idea than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would spell it out - use the term "Confidential" in place of the customer name; this way there is no ambiguity.  You could also make this term a link or provide a tool tip to provide further explanation i.e "This customer's name is confidential and cannot be displayed".

Providing an incorrect name or just using a colour would be confusing.  I think most people would think there was an error displaying the data rather than a business rule meaning it could not be displayed.  I think there are also issues using red (typically indicates a problem; also not clear with people with colour blindness).

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the customer name is confidential. I would suggest just putting that as the text, and with a soft red text color to give a better visual cue that it is confidential. Red is often the standard color for that sort of thing. If you want to stick with the default text color, *italicized* might be a better option than soft red.